# Что означает <p></p> в php?

Tags: php

Например: `print '<p>Hello</p>';`

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал что в php это что то другое означает.

Comment: @Riken вы можете принять ответ другого пользователя, тем самым закрыв вопрос и показав, что верным ответом был тот или другой. У меня отсюда не видно, где это, но скорее всего это "галка" под рейтингом ответа.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Это не PHP, это форматирование HTML - [абзац](http://htmlbook.ru/html/p)

Answer (score 4):

Это параграф. HTML розметка может выводится через php.